# Can you call the arrow (->) operator function manually?

Tags: c++, operators

If I have a `Foo *foo`, I can say `foo->bar()`.  Is it possible to call the `operator->()` function manually?  And if so, how would I pass it `bar()`?

Does it make a difference if it is `Foo foo` instead?

Maybe something like `foo.operator->(bar)`?

Comment: @Michael, obfuscate code obviously. :)

Comment: Lol, I was trying to be polite :)

Comment: You don't pass it `bar`. The overloadable `operator->` is a *unary* operator, acting on its LHS only. It returns either a pointer, or an object that in turn has `operator->` overloaded. Eventually you get a pointer, which is substituted in for the LHS. C++ functions can't take names as parameters, so there's no way to say "when `bar` is looked up in an instance of class `Foo`, do this:", as you might be used to from for example the `__getattr__` function in Python.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can. With overloaded `->` the `foo->bar()` expression is interpreted by the compiler as `foo.operator->()->bar()`. And this is exactly how you can call it "manually": `foo.operator->()->bar()`.

If your overloaded `operator ->` function is implemented "properly", i.e. it returns something that also supports operator `->` then there's not much point in using the "manual" syntax, since it is doing the same thing as the "non-manual" one.

The only case you'd need the "manual" syntax is when your implementation of overloaded `operator ->` returns something that does not support another application of `->`. An `int` value, for example.

Comment: As `foo` is a pointer, would that still be interpreted as `foo.operator->()->bar()`?   `.` or `->`?

Comment: @Nawaz can't overload operators unless at least one of the type is user-defined. If it were allowed, the call would be with the form `operator->(foo)->bar()` because only class types have members. Think of `operator+(int, T const&)` which *is* allowed provided `T` is user-defined: `0 + t` would be sugar for `operator+(0, t)`, **not** `0.operator+(t)`.

Comment: @Luc: I didn't understand your comment. My confusion was about `.` vs `->` in `foo.operator`

Comment: @Nawaz I assumed `foo` had type `Foo*`, as in the OP's question. If `foo` has a class type, e.g. `std::unique_ptr<Foo>`, then you are correct: `foo->bar` is equivalent to `foo.operator->()->bar`.

Comment: `operator->()` will be implicitly called, in a chain, as many times as necessary in order to get something that's of a pointer type, at which point the built-in logic for `->` (dereference the pointer and access the member) kicks in. (That can't be overridden because you can't overload operators for pointer types.) Of course, if the chain ends with a type that is neither a pointer nor has an overload (such as an `int`), then you get a compiler error.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

```
(*foo)->bar();               //syntax one   (implicit)
(*foo)->operaror->()->bar(); //syntax two   (explicit)
 foo->operator->()->bar();   //syntax three (explicit)
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to call the operator->() function manually?

There is no operator->() *function* because `foo` in your example is a pointer. For pointers, the behavior of `->` is defined by the language.

If the type `Foo` has an `operator->()` function, and you have `Foo *foo` defined, you can do this to call the `operator->()` function:

```
(*foo)->...;
```

Or you can use the direct call syntax:

```
(*foo)operator->()->...;
```